# whats the "Difference" between these identical meshes

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, boolean-modifier

I am just learning Python although have plenty of experience in Javascript and C++ amongst other languages.

As a "fairly straight forward" (lol) project I am creating Brio Train track pieces.

Straights and curves are easy but to create the junctions I decided to create two meshes, the block, and the rails which I can then use a boolean modifier to remove to create the grooves in the track piece (at this time I was going to do this outside of the script). This worked fine for the curved section of the junction but the for the straight section one rail (one half of the rail mesh) will not work as a boolean. I refactored my code to make each rail its own mesh and made the one that wasn't working a copy of the one that was but it still doesn't work when used as part of the boolean modifier.

[image: Boolean not happening]

```
import bpy
import math

width=0.3
length=1
height=0.05
turnRight=False
railHeight=-0.01
railWidth=0.03
guage=0.2

width=width/2
guage=guage/2

# make mesh
verts = []
edges = []
faces = []

negVerts1=[]
negEdges1=[]
negFaces1=[]
negVerts2=[]
negEdges2=[]
negFaces2=[]

#start of track
#righthand base
verts.append([width,0,0])
#righthand top edge
verts.append([width,0,height])
#lefthand rail edge
verts.append([-width,0,height])
#lefthand base
verts.append([-width,0,0])
#end of track
#righthand base
verts.append([width,length,0])
#righthand top edge
verts.append([width,length,height])
#lefthand rail edge
verts.append([-width,length,height])
#lefthand base
verts.append([-width,length,0])

#extend the length for the negative mesh
length+=0.0001

"""#righthand rail joint
negVerts1.append([guage+railWidth,-0.0001,height+0.01])
#righthand rail outside
negVerts1.append([guage+railWidth,-0.0001,height+railHeight])
#righthand rail inside
negVerts1.append([guage,-0.0001,height+railHeight])
#righthand rail inside joint
negVerts1.append([guage,-0.0001,height+0.01])
#righthand rail joint
negVerts1.append([guage+railWidth,length,height+0.01])
#righthand rail outside
negVerts1.append([guage+railWidth,length,height+railHeight])
#righthand rail inside
negVerts1.append([guage,length,height+railHeight])
#righthand rail inside joint
negVerts1.append([guage,length,height+0.01])"""

#lefthand rail inside joint
negVerts2.append([-guage-railWidth,-0.0001,height+0.01])
#lefthand rail inside
negVerts2.append([-guage-railWidth,-0.0001,height+railHeight])
#lefthand rail outside
negVerts2.append([-guage,-0.0001,height+railHeight])
#lefthand rail joint
negVerts2.append([-guage,-0.0001,height+0.01])
#lefthand rail inside joint
negVerts2.append([-guage-railWidth,length,height+0.01])
#lefthand rail inside
negVerts2.append([-guage-railWidth,length,height+railHeight])
#lefthand rail outside
negVerts2.append([-guage,length,height+railHeight])
#lefthand rail joint
negVerts2.append([-guage,length,height+0.01])


faces.append([0,4,5,1])
faces.append([1,5,6,2])
faces.append([2,6,7,3])
faces.append([3,7,4,0])
faces.append([0,1,2,3])
faces.append([4,7,6,5])

negFaces1.append([0,4,5,1])
negFaces1.append([1,5,6,2])
negFaces1.append([2,6,7,3])
negFaces1.append([3,7,4,0])
negFaces1.append([0,3,2,1])
negFaces1.append([4,5,6,7])

negFaces2.append([0,4,5,1])
negFaces2.append([1,5,6,2])
negFaces2.append([2,6,7,3])
negFaces2.append([3,7,4,0])
negFaces2.append([0,3,2,1])
negFaces2.append([4,5,6,7])

for v in range(8):
    negVerts1.append(negVerts2[v].copy())
    negVerts1[v][0]*=-1

#negFaces.append([8,12,13,9])
#negFaces.append([9,13,14,10])
#negFaces.append([10,14,15,11])
#negFaces.append([11,15,12,8])
#negFaces.append([8,9,10,11])
#negFaces.append([12,15,14,13])

new_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('junctionTrack')
new_mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
new_mesh.update()
rightRail = bpy.data.meshes.new('right rail')
rightRail.from_pydata(negVerts1, negEdges1, negFaces1)
rightRail.update()
leftRail = bpy.data.meshes.new('left rail')
leftRail.from_pydata(negVerts2, negEdges2, negFaces2)
leftRail.update()

# make object from mesh
new_object = bpy.data.objects.new('junctionTrack', new_mesh)
rightRailObject = bpy.data.objects.new('right rail', rightRail)
leftRailObject= bpy.data.objects.new('left rail', leftRail)

#sub=new_object.modifiers.new(type="BOOLEAN",name="groove")
#sub.object=new_negobject
#sub.operation="DIFFERENCE"

# make collection
new_collection = bpy.data.collections.new('junction_collection')
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(new_collection)
# add object to scene collection
new_collection.objects.link(new_object)
new_collection.objects.link(rightRailObject)
new_collection.objects.link(leftRailObject)
```

Comment: I should mention that I have checked the normals, this had been a problem prior to this but swapping the 2nd and 3rd vertices of the wrong faces solved it leaving the stated issue.

Comment: Just FYI, it's better (general etiquette) to click the "Edit" link below your post to include other/new information.

Comment: Hello and welcome. A screenshot and a complete, executable script would be very helpful to answer your question. I had to guess and added the missing variables. Now I have a part of a railroad line and wonder what the actual question and problem are. -- ok, faces are flipped. That's bad. But how do you want to create junctions? What is about the mentioned *Boolean* modifier?

Comment: Thanks Blunder, I have updated the code to contain my entire script and included a screenshot. The curved section of the junction is in a separate script and works without a problem, I am just trying to understand why this doesn't work, it would be tedious to do it without using a script but my problem is trying to learn scripting and I want to know what I did wrong/different between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The question is now much more understandable and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in orientation of faces. You can check this by switching Face orientation overlay:

[image]

As you see, some faces marked red, which means whey are facing backwards. To make boolean work, they should face to us.

This is determined by the winding order of the face. Then you create faces like this `faces.append([0,4,5,1])` the order matters.  Given an ordering of the  vertices, a face can appear to have a clockwise winding or counter-clockwise winding. Clockwise means that the vertices, in order, rotate clockwise around the center. Counter-clockwise means that the vertices, in order, rotate counter-clockwise around the triangle's center:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks, I had been checking the normals in edit mode rather than the face orientation, I understand the winding order, and I have just realised the mistake in the code: negVerts1[v][0]*=-1 this mirrors the vertices thus reversing the winding. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The weird results come from Boolean operations. They are not perfect and are sensitive to position, shape, overlapping geometry and so on. You could try using Fast solver, that most of the time is more exact than the Exact one or move your objects slightly, but if you aim to have geometry generated procedurally and you need it to work reliably in unknown situations, I  wouldn't recommend counting on Booleans because you never know when problems like this might happen.

If you stick with Booleans, it's probably better to use one Boolean modifier with Operand Type set to "Collection" and add your objects used for cutting to a collection:

[image]

Comment: Originally I was only creating 1 mesh to subtract which would mean only 1 modifier, but split it into two to try and identify the problem. I think I have resolved that now, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What Martynas Žiemys wrote is correct but the main problem is the **flipped normals**. A few of the faces are turned inside out. The *Boolean* modifier does not like this in *Exact* mode. The *Fast* mode is more error-tolerant but the result will have flipped normals, too. That's bad and can cause further problems.

If you enable the *Face Orientation* overlay you will see red faces and actually, the *left rail* and *right rail* objects are not identical.

[image: screenshot]

I guess you have to change the order of the vertices that create these faces in your script.

By the way, wouldn't it be easier to just create one *rail* object, then duplicate and move it to create the track? → fewer vertices that can be messed up.

Comment: In edit mode I checked all the normals and everything seemed fine, I didn't flip any normals but I did reverse the order I created some faces in order to get the normals I wanted/expected. Thanks for your help